# Calculate salary base on total Hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How can I calculate salary base on total Hours? I have two tables and a query that will compute the total hours per day.

Table `officer_timelogs`

```
employee_id      record_time             Day      type
--------------------------------------------------------
125         2018-02-27 18:03:31.000    Tuesday     1
125         2018-02-27 07:54:03.000    Tuesday     0
```

Table `officer_rate`

```
employee_id     designation      salary
125             programmer       100 (hour)
```

SQL Query:

```
select
    employee_id, 
    [Date], DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)as [Day], 
    [Hours] = right(concat('00', diff / 3600), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2)
from (
    select
        employee_id, 
        [date] = cast(record_time as date),
        diff = datediff(ss, min(iif(type = 0, record_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null)))
    from
        officer_timelogs
    where employee_id = '125'
    group by employee_id, cast(record_time as date)
) t
order by date desc
```

Output:

```
employee_id   Date       Day           Hours
    125    2018-03-02   Friday      09 : 00 : 00
    125    2018-03-01   Thursday    10 : 10 : 49
    125    2018-02-28   Wednesday   10 : 14 : 11
    125    2018-02-27   Tuesday     10 : 09 : 28
    125    2018-02-26   Monday      10 : 13 : 34
```

Desired output (I want to retrieve data like this)

```
employee_id   Date       Day           Hours        Salary
    125    2018-03-02   Friday      09 : 00 : 00     900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've done the most complex part.

Since you already have the worked time, you just need to multiply by the salary, like this:

```
select
    t.employee_id, 
    [Date], DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)as [Day], 
    [Hours] = right(concat('00', diff / 3600), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2),
    diff * r.salary / 3600 AS Salary

from (
    select
        employee_id, 
        [date] = cast(record_time as date),
        diff = datediff(ss, min(iif(type = 0, record_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null)))
    from
        officer_timelogs
    where employee_id = '125'
    group by employee_id, cast(record_time as date)
) t
INNER JOIN officer_rate r ON t.employee_id = r.employee_id
order by date desc
```

You can check it live on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a80f/1/0).

#### Edit: Code and demo updated with OT rate:

In this case, you need to check if OT should be applied. If the person worked 8h or less, we consider the regular rate. The difference for the 8h is calculated by considering 20% of the hourly salary:

```
select
    t.employee_id, 
    [Date], DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)as [Day], 
    [Hours] = right(concat('00', diff / 3600), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2),
    CAST(
    CASE WHEN diff <= 3600 * 8
        THEN diff * r.salary / 3600
        ELSE 
            (3600 * 8 * r.salary / 3600) -- salary x 8h / work
            + (diff - (3600 * 8)) * r.salary * 0.2 /3600 -- OT work
        END AS decimal(10, 2)) AS Salary
from (
    select
        employee_id, 
        [date] = cast(record_time as date),
        diff = datediff(ss, min(iif(type = 0, record_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null)))
    from
        officer_timelogs
    where employee_id = '125'
    group by employee_id, cast(record_time as date)
) t
INNER JOIN officer_rate r ON t.employee_id = r.employee_id
order by date desc;
```

[Demo updated here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf36a/1/0)

Comment: How can I calculate the exceeded hrs/mins from the total Hours? example employee needs only 8 hours per day then the exceeded hours will calculate as OT rate.

Comment: Where is defined the OT rate ? In a different table ? What is it?

Comment: The OT rate is 20% of the rate per hour.

Comment: how can i exclude 1 hour so it will not count the lunch break.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this. I bet you need to convert hours to decimal such that 1 hour and 30 minutes will make 1.5

```
select
    employee_id, 
    [Date], DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date)as [Day], 
    [Hours] = right(concat('00', diff / 3600), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 3600 / 60), 2) + ' : ' + right(concat('00', diff % 60), 2),
    Salary = <However you need to get hour(s) as a decimal> * tl2.salary
from (
    select
        employee_id, 
        [date] = cast(record_time as date),
        diff = datediff(ss, min(iif(type = 0, record_time, null)), max(iif(type = 1, record_time, null)))
    from
        officer_timelogs
    where employee_id = '125'
    group by employee_id, cast(record_time as date)
) t
INNER JOIN officer_rate tl2 ON tl2.employee_id=t.employee_id
order by date desc
```

Comment: It is possible to group Tuesday through Monday and sum the salary?